# ExtJS Reactor boilerplate installation error (index.html not found)!

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I am trying to run ExtJS over React, as my team is committed to React development. I've personally worked before with ExtJS, so wanted to see if I could combine the power of ExtJS with React. But I couldn't make it work yet.

## What I have done so far:

Downloaded the ExtJS 6 zip and unzipped into a folder "ext" - as suggested in readme.md.
When I run the build, it gives me the following error message

[image: Error message]

My directory structure looks like this:

[image]

Can anybody give me a pointer where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to update your Cmd version, 6.2.1 is out.

Comment: If you have access to the Sencha support portal you should try directly Cmd 6.5 beta as it's better suited for the reactor

Comment: Thanks, indeed updating Sencha Cmd version 6.2.1 resolved my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

@pagep's suggestion worked! Updated to 6.2.1 of Sencha Cmd and the problem resolved. Thanks